# Получить одно фото с веб-камеры C++

Tags: c++, api, web-camera

Здравствуйте! Я знаю, что данная тема уже поднималась, но все же вопрос задам.
Как можно получить один кадр с веб-камеры средствами С++, без сторонних библиотек(имею ввиду OpenCV)? Как здесь можно использовать WinAPI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939168/how-do-i-read-a-video-camera-in-a-win32-c-program